# Нужны ли в следующем предложении знаки препинания?

Tags: запятые

*Не бойся до тебя очередь дойдет.*

Answer (score 1):

Да. Нужна запятая после `бойся`, так как это 2 простых предложения в составе сложного:

`(Ты) не бойся, до тебя очередь дойдет.`

С запятой это простая констатация: не делай то, будет это. Но здесь 2 части связаны логически. Там лучше поставить двоеточие, если хочется подчеркнуть причину, почему именно не стоит бояться.

`(Ты) не бойся: до тебя очередь дойдет.`

Answer (score 1):

Этому предложению **не хватает контекста,** так как здесь возможны два смысловых варианта.

1) Ирония и скрытая угроза: ***Не бойся,  до тебя очередь (тоже) дойдет.***

Например:

*Погоди, Симкова спалили, скоро и до вас очередь дойдет…*  [А. И. Пантелеев (1938-1952)]

2) Иронии нет, значение прямое: ***Не бойся,  до тебя очередь дойдет.***

Запятая ставится в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП), первое предложение односоставное.